# Kotlin toArray vs asArray

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Just wondering, what's the difference between to- and as- prefixes the Kotlin libraries?

```
var buffer:ByteArray
// what's the difference between these two
buffer.toUByteArray()
buffer.asUByteArray()
```

I would imagine one refers to a copy of the array, and the other is more of a wrapper pointing to the same values in memory, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toUByteArray: Returns an array of type UByteArray, which is a copy of this array where each element is an unsigned reinterpretation of the corresponding element of this array.

asUByteArray: Returns an array of type UByteArray, which is a view of this array where each element is an unsigned reinterpretation of the corresponding element of this array.

Explanation about difference between in *copy* and *view*:

> While executing the functions, some of them return a copy of the input array, while some return the view. When the contents are physically stored in another location, it is called Copy. If on the other hand, a different view of the same memory content is provided, we call it as View

References:

[toUByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-u-byte-array.html)

[asUByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-u-byte-array.html)

[NumPy - Copies & Views](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_copies_and_views.htm)